# CodeIgniter Can't sent email

Tags: php, codeigniter, sendmail

I am using fedora in my DEV machine and tring to send mail via codeignigter.
the sendmail is working fine, the PHP mail() function is working fine as well.
but for some reason, codeigniter isnt working with the following settings that it also configured in the php.ini:

```
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
```

the error that i am getting is:

```
Exit status code: 64
Unable to open a socket to Sendmail. Please check settings.
Unable to send email using PHP Sendmail. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

Thanks

Comment: 1) post your php code 2) what happens when you use the mail protocol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting is not a CodeIgniter error, its a PHP error.

If you're working on a local dev server, say a desktop in your house, theres a good chance that your Fedora install didn't set up any mail system. Try setting your protocol to SMTP and setting a server/user/pass in your config/email.php file, like so:

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.isp.net';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'username';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';
```

Alternatively, I believe you can set this up in your php.ini file as well and use the settings server wide.

Answer (score 1):

Most common problem is not having e-mail user setup... You mention DEV server - double check for it. Mail () will not send e-mail if sender does not exist

Comment: Thanks, this worked great for me. Often development and live servers will have similar web configurations but only the live server will have mail users correctly configured. This causes email issues when testing (strangely enough even if you try to route mail to SMTP on the live server).